# Android: creating a "first time user" activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to have an activity with registration for the users who run my app for the very first time. I don't want the user to be able to go past this registration activity, if he doesn't want to register, he has to close the app.

I can check whether the user is registered by storing the in `SharedPreferences`, that seems to work without any problems. So what I have so far in my MainActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (needsRegistration()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
}
```

I am having the following problems with this:

- I am not sure where I should start the registration activity (before or after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` ?)
- The MainActivity seems to keep working in the background and creates errors (because the user is not registered)
- The user can go to the MainActivity by pressing the back button

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure where I should start the registration activity (before or after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) ?)

You should have your `super()` call as the first call when doing opening functions like `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, etc.... This way the function can do everything that the `super()` call needs to in order for the function to be ready. This isn't always a problem but safer to make the call first. Finishing functions such as `onBackPressed()`, `finish()`, etc... should have the `super()` call after you do your cleanup such as saving data.

> The MainActivity seems to keep working in the background and creates errors (because the user is not registered)

Make the `RegistrationActivity` the launcher `Activity` and check if the user is registered and if so start the `MainActivity` else display your registration code or whatever you do in this case.

> The user can go to the MainActivity by pressing the back button

See the previous solution. If the `MainActivity` is only started from the `RegistrationActivity` then this won't be an issue.

Checking the `SharedPreferences` to see if the user is registered shouldn't cause much of a delay so you can do this before creating the `layout` for that `Activity` and go to the `MainActivity` if they are registered. If for some reason you are noticing much of a delay then you can make a splash screen to show your logo or whatever while you check for registered or not then take appropriate actions by going to either the registration or main `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you, swapping the activities and adding `android:noHistory="true"` to the registration activity's manifest solved the problems.However, now when I run the app as a registered user I can see the title "Register" in the action bar for a fraction of a second, which is slightly annoying. Any way to solve this?

Comment: That's where implementing a splash screen comes in handy. Unless you get rid of the `ActionBar` in the register `Activity` if you don't need it.